# Python 3.7.8 Imports an uninstalled Tensorflow Version

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pip, tensorflow2.0

I am currently trying to change my Tensorflow version in Python from 2.2.0 to 1.15.0, but I cannot seem to get python to import the correct module.

First, I do:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

After the uninstallation is complete, I do:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

But in testing the Tensorflow version after changing the installed version, I get:

> `tensorflow.__version__`

ouptut: '2.2.0'

I'm currently trying to see if there is a hidden library in a different location, but am pretty stumped. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps this is an environment issue? Can you run python inside your anaconda environment and check the version?

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem with python modules when the environment is messy. To help track it down, you should look at the value of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and the location of the imported package. That is, inside python, print this: `tensorflow.__file__`

Answer (score 0):

Use `python -m pip uninstall tensorflow` and `python -m pip install tensorflow==1.15.0`. Replace `python` with whichever Python interpret you use to run your script.

The `python -m pip` syntax uses the `pip` module for the `python` interpreter. This syntax is helpful when you have multiple python installations and it is not clear which interpreter or environment `pip` points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python3 you could try running `pip3 install tensorflow==1.15.0`.

These issues happen a lot when the environment is messy. You can install Anaconda and create an environment and install the version that you want. This is how: (I used 3.6 as an example. Do whatever version you like.)

```
conda create -n environmentname python=3.6
conda activate environmentname
```

You can also run `conda deactivate` to deactivate the environment. When the environment is active, run `pip install tensorflow==1.15.0`.