# Fake tensorflow importable even when uninstalled

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, python-import

My problem could be potentially related to this:
[Python 3.7.8 Imports an uninstalled Tensorflow Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569179/python-3-7-8-imports-an-uninstalled-tensorflow-version)

I am trying to test some conditions in my code on conditions when it fails to import tensorflow.
So I uninstalled tensorflow using `pip uninstall` (which successfully ended without error) and tried to run the code again. The problem is it still can import tensorflow from somewhere!

The 'fake' tensorflow loaded does not have any functions it should have, so basically the only thing that works is

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__file__)
```

This returns None, so I cannot even find where it is loading this thing from. Even `.__version__` tells me there is no such function.

Has anyone experienced this? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: try uninstalling with `pip uninstall tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu` multiple times. And from description, you might have named some file in same directory `tensorflow.py`?

Comment: @BijayRegmi Thank you for the suggestions! I did try uninstalling tensorflow multiple times, but pip couldn't find tensorflow to uninstall.(I tried uninstalling every package that had tensorflow name in it) I do not have tensorflow.py inside the directory. If I was loading tensorflow from some file, I'm guessing it would have returned something in tensorflow.__file__?

Comment: Did you try restarting the kernel/runtime or by opening a new notebook and check for the same (if tensorflow exists) after uninstalling the tensorflow using code `pip uninstall tensorflow`? Please provide some more details like python/tensorflow version and the platform/OS you are using if this issue still persists.

Comment: @TFer2 I tried multiple times using ipython, so I don't think it was a notebook issue. I did try `pip uninstall tensorflow` but pip failed to find tensorflow. I was using Python 3.8.13 conda environment, TF 2.10.0 on Windows 10.